# Visualising Gantt chart distribution

Tags: python, data-visualization, boxplot, operations-research

I perform $n$ simulations of operations planning. I can plot a gantt chart for each simulation, but I am interested in visualising the variability of the whole simulation set : I want a Gantt visualisation which includes information about :

- the distribution of starting dates $d_s$
- the distribution of durations $\Delta$ (or ending dates $d_e = d_s + \Delta$)

I thought of a plot  derived from Gantt Plot where each process is represented by a box with information showing mean and specific quantiles for starting dates and ending dates (inspired by boxplots).

[image: sketch]

Do you have other ideas / recommandations on how to visualize the variability of a task's properties in a Gantt chart ?

Additionnally, do you have any idea of how to implement this in Python ? Ideally as an interactive visualisation ? I thought of creating a new plotly class derived from their Boxplot.

Thanks :)

EDIT :
here is a data sample for starting dates (in real life there are thousands of rows -simulations- and hundreds of columns -processes):

```
key_op     1     2_FS     3_SF     4_FF     5_SS     6_FS     7_SF     8_FF     9_SS     10_FS     11_SF     12_FF     13_SS
    0     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    1     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    2     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    3     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    4     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    5     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    6     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    7     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    8     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
    9     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 3:00     4/1/18 21:00     5/1/18 0:00     5/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 3:00     5/1/18 21:00     6/1/18 0:00     6/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 3:00     3/1/18 21:00     4/1/18 0:00     4/1/18 0:00
```

ending dates:

```
key_op   1   2_FS   3_SF   4_FF   5_SS   6_FS   7_SF   8_FF   9_SS   10_FS   11_SF   12_FF   13_SS
    0   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    1   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    2   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    3   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    4   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    5   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    6   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    7   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    8   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
    9   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 6:00   5/1/18 0:00   5/1/18 3:00   5/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 6:00   6/1/18 0:00   6/1/18 3:00   6/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 6:00   4/1/18 0:00   4/1/18 3:00   4/1/18 3:00
```

and links between operations based on :

```
op_id  previous_op
1  
2  1FS
3  1SF
4  1FF
5  1SS
6  1FS+1 day
7  1SF+1 day
8  1FF+1 day
9  1SS+1 day
10  1FS-1 day
11  1SF-1 day
12  1FF-1 day
13  1SS-1 day
```

Comment: Do you really only have 2 values (start date & duration)? If so, a gantt chart seems like overkill.  Gantt charts are typically sensible when there are multiple processes to visualize / keep track of, and their starting & ending points are linked between processes.

Comment: I have several processes in a planning, which are represented by their respective starting date, duration, ending date, and by their links to other processes. However visualizing the links between operations is a bonus, what I am mostly interested in is the variability on starting dates, duration and ending dates for each operation in a Gantt style visualisation

Comment: Can you provide a small, example dataset for people to work with? It really sounds to me like the right visualization is a scatterplot of duration vs start date.

Comment: Thanks, I just added sample datasets to my question. I am not sure that scatterplots would bea readable if there is a big amount of simulations. Besides, I am looking for a visualisation which is readable by non-statisticians.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. Does a simulation entail many sub-processes, with each row an independent simulation & each column is a sub-process? Should there be hours? (These all seem to be on the same day.)

Comment: Yes, each row is an independent simulation, and each column a subprocess. There should indeed be hours ! I'll fix this

Comment: Use datetimes as the dayatype, then figure out what format to render them (rather than doing date-arithmetic on ad-hoc culumns). Depending on how you want to express runtimes as fractional days(/weeks?/months?/quarters?/hours?/minutes?/seconds?/milliseconds?), and start-dates (format?), you end up in lots of grief with date-and-time-units (and formats, and localization).  It helps if you narrow this down, and post example with specific numbers and units. Is it okay to just say "Day 112" or 'Week 16" or do you want "Saturday, April 22nd, 2023"?

Comment: Currently the boxplot that you sketched would depict the variability in **start-times** and **end-times**, not in *start-times* and *duration*. Attempting to (indirectly) visually understand variability in duration from that plot means you'd have to factor in both the varability in *start-times* and *end-times*. So if that isn't what you want, recast this as separate plots of *start-times* and *duration*, but then that wouldn't be a Gantt chart. So, you have to decide which you want?